# JavaScript (NodeJS) equivalent for PHP's call_user_func_array()

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Is there any equivalent function in JavaScript (NodeJS) similar to PHP's 
`call_user_func_array` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Which allows to call a function with array of parameters.

In my case, I have to call `util.format` with parameters that will be in an array.

Here is very simple example trying to show it.

```
var util = require("util");

function my_fundtion(items) {
  var format_string = "";
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    format_string += " %s";
  }
  return util.format(format_string, /* here I want to pass items in items array */);
}
```

Comment: In your example, do you mean:
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    format += " " + items[i];
  }

Are you also doing a string replace on format_string from your util.format?

Comment: Javascript has : `myFunction.apply(object or null, args)`

Comment: @thiswayup No, it is to get same number of placeholders as array items.

Comment: BTW, `format_string` will always be empty

Comment: @LuisMasuelli corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has:

```
call_user_func_array('myfunc', array(1, 2, "foo", false));
```

While JS has:

```
myfunc.apply(null, [1, 2, "foo", false]);
```

The first `null` goes in the position of an object. You will make use of that if the function is intended to be a method. An example on using such invocation would be to slice array-like objects which are not arrays at all but seem like one (like the `arguments` object inside of a function):

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, []);
```

Generally speaking, the syntax is:

```
(afunction).apply(obj|null, array of arguments)
```

You can try this:

```
function my_fundtion(items) {
    var format_string = "";
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        format_string += " %s";
    }
    var new_items = items.slice();
    new_items.unshift(format_string);
    return util.format.apply(null, new_items);
}
```

IMHO that's the wrong approach for a function. Have you tried the following?

```
function my_fundtion(items) {
    return items.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! myfunction.apply() helped. Yeah, array.join() to be used, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `call_user_func_array` call function referenced by the function name which is in string. So, in JS we need to use `eval`.

Example:

```
const popup = (msg) => {
 alert(msg);
}

const subject = {
 popup(msg) {
  alert(msg);
 }
}
```

So,

```
eval("popup").apply(null, ['hi'])
eval("subject.popup").apply(null, ['hi'])
```

Correct me. If i wrong. ;)